# Lint warning Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-lint

This tag and its children can be replaced by one  and a compound drawable

> Issue: Checks whether the current node can be replaced by a TextView
>   using compound drawables.
>
> A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView can be more
>   efficiently handled as a compound drawable

I am getting this lint warning in one of my `Layout`.I am not getting what does it mean by `Compound Layout`.Please explain or provide any suitable links.

Comment: You can always click on it and hit "Ignore Type" :D .. Just a thought, since it's a warning and not an error. Probably as it says, there could be minor performance issues. I honestly don't think that could hinder your app.

Comment: @Rahul: You should be happy that DroidShruti asked for how to improve his code (and therefore wants to learn about the problem). Your recommendation of just ignoring it doesn't help him/her in learning. And we all want to get more apps in the Android market with a professional touch, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your 'complex' layout with just one view:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textViewId"
     ...
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawableName" />
```

Comment: +1 - @DroidShruti Lint is suggesting you to use built in function of showing drawable on TextView's either side(top, bottom, left, right)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes image's styling is too complex, to use it just as compound drawable along with textView, so, the best decision here is to ignore that warning:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables" />
```